# PHP/MySQL DELETE on multiple rows with inner join

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I'm currently working on a website as a school project. I'm having trouble while trying to delete multiples rows in my database, here's the query:

`$dbh->query("DELETE FROM ENSEIGNE E INNER JOIN COURS C ON C.ID_COURS = E.ID_COURS WHERE E.ID_PROF = '$id_prof' and C.ID_MATIERE = '$matt' ");`

with `$id_prof` and `$matt` which can be replaced by a number inferior to 5.

The two tables have only two columns:

- ENSEIGNE has ID_PROF and ID_COURS
- COURS has ID_COURS and ID_MATIERE

My problem is that I get an error 1064 while running this command and after 3h changing the query I still haven't found the problem.

Comment: some databases don't like qoutes arround integers `C.ID_MATIERE = '$matt'` use `C.ID_MATIERE = $matt` instead if $matt == 5 also for `$id_prof`

Comment: try DELETE e.*, c.* FROM look [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-join/)

Comment: thank you Aleksandar Miladinovic, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to delete from `ENSEIGNE` then query would be

```
DELETE E 
FROM ENSEIGNE E 
INNER JOIN COURS C ON C.ID_COURS = E.ID_COURS 
WHERE E.ID_PROF = '$id_prof' 
and C.ID_MATIERE = '$matt'
```

And for deleting from both tables

```
DELETE E , C
FROM ENSEIGNE E 
INNER JOIN COURS C ON C.ID_COURS = E.ID_COURS 
WHERE E.ID_PROF = '$id_prof' 
and C.ID_MATIERE = '$matt'
```